# Can TeamCity trigger builds for new Git branches/tags?

Tags: teamcity

I only managed to get TeamCity trigger builds for new changes in branches, but not when a branch or tag is created. I'd like to automatically trigger a build when I create a version tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Properly Configure Feature Branch CI with TeamCity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739180/how-do-i-properly-configure-feature-branch-ci-with-teamcity)

Comment: @Vadzim Doesn't seem to be a duplicate, the question here was about triggering builds on tag creation, not commits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@stevechapman, thanks

Sorry, I understood this question wrong. If you want to run a build as soon as your tag is created, teamcity currently does not have a feature that runs out of the box. You can:

1. Configure a git post commit hook that runs a build target after you create your tag
2. Or you can have a custom teamcity target that scans git repo for  newly created tags and run if you find any.
3. In case you are creating the tag in a build target in teamcity, you can create a dependent target that will run after your original target and work on the tag that you just created.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me. I've set branch specification to `+:refs/heads/*` and branch filter to `+:*` in VCS triggers. It detects new branches but they are listed as Inactive Branches and no builds are triggered until changes are committed to the branch.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - VCS / remote run triggers will only trigger on detection of a changeset - creating a tag / branch alone will not cause a build to trigger this way.  An alternative approach I can think of to trigger a build is to fire off a TeamCity API call via a [git hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), but  that can get complicated...

Comment: Try this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122891/nightly-build-for-release-branch-if-branch-exists/28448113#28448113

Comment: You can now use configuration parameter `teamcity.vcsTrigger.runBuildInNewEmptyBranch=true` to tell TeamCity to build on tag creation -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-43606