# How Do I Properly Configure Feature Branch CI with TeamCity

Tags: git, teamcity-8.0, feature-branch

I am currently trying to [set up TeamCity to build all the branches which are not my team's main branches](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Working+with+Feature+Branches). I have had trouble getting this to work, and have only gotten this to function with the default branch. Our repository has the following branches: master, Daily-build, Branch-Alex, and others with similar names. I pretty much want this build configuration to run on pushes that do not include master. Here are some pictures of my configuration:

1. VCS Root:

[image: VCS Root Settings]

2. Trigger Settings:

[image: Trigger Settings]

3. Current Build Config:

[image: Current Build Config]

TL:DR - Is there a better tutorial for setting up feature branch building in team city?

Bonus Points - How do I make the names just be the branch names rather than the "ref/heads/Daily-build"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, my problem was a simple typo:

`+:ref/heads/*` should be written as `+:refs/heads/*`

Comment: Bonus points : use +:refs/heads/(*) in your VCS root branch specs to control the branch name. whatever is matched between the brackets will be used as the branch name.

Comment: More than two years later, I did the same thing too.  Who would've thought that a missing 's' would cause so much headache?