# Nightly build for release branch if branch exists

Tags: teamcity, git-flow

I'd like to set up a nightly build for my release branch. Since I'm using git-flow I don't always have a relase branch so I would like it to build it if it can find a branch with a pattern of:

`refs/heads/release-*`

Any idea of how to get teamcity to perform this action for me?

Comment: I don't know if this works with Git, but have you tried a scheduled trigger on the build configuration with a branch filter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **Branch Filter** in the **Trigger** and set the only filter as

```
+:release-*
```

Also in **Version Control** under **Branch Specification** use

```
+:(release-*)
```

I also had similar issue and solved it as given above.
I think this would solve your  problem too.

Comment: I'm trying to do this exact thing and I have `+:(release/*)`, but it doesn't appear to be working.  The build configuration just never does anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup the a CI trigger based on the VCS with a branch spec as you've outlined, it should automatically pick it up when it's created with git-flow and stop when it's merged. Have you had a specific issue with this functionality?