# Team City: branch specification based on parent

Tags: teamcity, branch

So when I create a branch in my repo - it's either a bugfix or a feature.  The thing to note is it could either branch from master or X.  In team city I want to do a branch specification so that I will only build if the feature or bug fix came from X not from master, I am wondering if perhaps it is something like:

+: feature* ^X

+: bugfix* ^X

Or if there is a different way of handling this, please advise.  I want to build if a bugfix or a feature came off of a specific branch.

thanks

Comment: try to gather some info from `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122891/nightly-build-for-release-branch-if-branch-exists/28448113#28448113`

Answer (score 0):

Teamcity won't know the parent rbanch of your branch. So you can do things

1. Give a logical name to all branches that come from "X" ,(for ex call them x-)and set a filter to only run on x-* named branches
2. Within the teamcity target , run a git command to find the parent branch and exit silently/failure if the parent branch is not the X-branch (this feature will not work if you delete branch X. It will then point to the parent of branch X , which might well be master)

You can use the below snippet

```
current_branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
parent_branch=`git show-branch -a | ack '\*' | ack -v "$current_branch" | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' | sed 's/[\^~].*//'`
```

Comment: 1. is most logical, but the branches are from Jira types so we can only add 1 filter, and we really need 2 filters.  2.  Is there any chance of getting an example of this, I think this is the route I need to go.