# TeamCity trigger build first time and on changed code

Tags: teamcity, cicd

In order to limit the number of (very long) builds in TeanCity I need to configure a run to trigger build on the *first* branch commit and if some files in the code were changed. I did find the option in the VCS Trigger to set the file wildcard rules.

However, is there a way to configure the build to trigger unconditionally, but only the *first* time?

TeamCity Enterprise 2023.05.4 (build 129421)

Comment: sounds like you want a scheduled trigger @ specific time but set with VCS changes ?

Comment: Not time - first push of a branch.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-43606   did you see this ?   Came from comment in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356893/can-teamcity-trigger-builds-for-new-git-branches-tags

Comment: @PeterMoore No I haven't. Thanks for the pointer - so the solution is to set `teamcity.vcsTrigger.runBuildInNewEmptyBranch` to `true`. I still need to test it.

Comment: If it works I recomend answer your own question so others can benefit

Comment: Update: it looks that this option only works with _empty_ branches.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. Make a command line job to create an artifact in the checkout dir.

```
if [ -f build.lock ]; then
    exit 1
else
    touch build.lock
    exit 0
fi
```

Then make another job to build if that succeeds. You can then adjust the logic to check if you want to clear that file by doing a few git commands in that dir.